# LINQPad and <connectionStrings configSource="..." /> and error 80131904

Tags: linqpad

Recently I've changed all .config files in our family of .NET projects to share the common DB connectivity:

```
<connectionStrings configSource=".\connectionStrings.config" />
```

where connectionStrings.config is supplied by pre-build event.
It seems to me that LINQpad 4.55.03 (Premium edition) does not support such kind of connection string externalization - it needs embedded connection string definition.

The file **connectionStrings.config** is on the path set in LINQPad's propeties, it is also copied to target bin folder where .dll with DB Context resides, LINQpad's connection test has succeeded, LINQpad is able to list entities from DB, but **no query** can bee executed at all - the result is error 80131904.

I got around by using *linqpad.config*, copying  section with real definitions there. I had to clear path to config file in the connection properties.

Is there a way to refer app.config as I did before or is *linqpad.config* only way to make it running?

Thanks, pf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must use LINQPad.config.

- **LINQPad.exe.config** is for the LINQPad GUI.
- **LINQPad.config** is for your queries.

When you test a connection that loads custom assemblies, LINQPad should use the LINQPad.config file. It sounds like it's using the LINQPad.exe.config in your case. What kind of connection is it?

Comment: This is local DB on development machine, connection string:  _<add name="CashPlannerContext" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=CashPlannerDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />_